# android Detect which way user swipes finger over picture

Tags: android

How can i detect which way i user swipes the picture if they swipe it right then (DO SOMETHING) if they swipe it left then (DO SOMETHING)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection

Answer (score 0):

you can get the array of screen touch locations from event.getX(x) (for example event.getX(0) means latest motion event and getX(1) means previous to latest). In this you can apply a formula to detect in which side are you swiping.

For Right..
    { 
        if(event.getX(0)- event.getX(1) > 0)
    // You swiped to right
    }
and similarly for left (i.e. xxxxxx < 0).